# Remover espaços entre uma pagina e outra

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Index Page
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $about = new WP_Query( 'pagename=home' ); ?>
<?php if( $about->have_posts() ) : $about->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endif; ?> 

<?php $service = new WP_Query( 'pagename=service' ); ?>
<?php if( $service->have_posts() ) : $service->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endif; ?> 

<?php $portfolio = new WP_Query( 'pagename=portfolio' ); ?>
<?php if( $portfolio->have_posts() ) : $portfolio->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

O codigo acima funciona mas gera um espaço entre uma pagina e outra como faço para remover isto?

Comment: Tem certeza que é no PHP?

Comment: Esse codigo fez uma pequena parte de mim morrer... Você não precisa botar <?php para cada função, apenas coloque um e faça quantos statements forem nescessários. Quanto a pergunta, precisamos que mostre a parte com HTML para avaliarmos onde os espaçoes estão surgindo...

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa (e nem deve) abrir a tag PHP a cada linha. Tudo que estiver entre `<?php` e `?>` será interpretado pelo servidor como código em PHP. Também não é necessário utilizra `?>` no final do arquivo, a não ser que exista algum código HTML após a última instrução PHP.

No seu caso, o código ficaria assim:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Index Page
*/

 get_header(); 
 $about = new WP_Query( 'pagename=home' ); 
 if( $about->have_posts() ) : $about->the_post(); 
 the_content(); 
 endif;  

 $service = new WP_Query( 'pagename=service' ); 
 if( $service->have_posts() ) : $service->the_post(); 
 the_content(); 
 endif;  

 $portfolio = new WP_Query( 'pagename=portfolio' ); 
 if( $portfolio->have_posts() ) : $portfolio->the_post(); 
 the_content(); 
 endif;  
 get_footer();
```